# setViewControllers() animation super fast/choppy for UIPageViewController with next button

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

I have a page view controller which initializes all its view controllers in `viewDidLoad()` method (4 in total). I implemented `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` so that the page view controller knows what view controller to load on demand. Everything works smoothly when I swipe through the pages.

I additionally added a `UIButton` which lets you go onto the next page (if there is one). In order to achieve that I came up with the following code:

```
 func goToNextPage()
 {
    // This is the last vc
    if self.currentIndex == self.controllers.count - 1
    {
        return
    }

    // Go to next vc
    self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex + 1
    let nextVC = self.controllers[ self.currentIndex ]
    self.setViewControllers( [ nextVC ], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil )
}
```

For some reason when I press the this button to go to a page I HAVE NOT SEEN before the animation appears to be really fast/choppy. However, when I press the button to navigate to a page I HAVE SEEN before, the animation runs smoothly as expected.

Does anyone know how to fix this bug? What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Does this happen with an arbitrary view controller (an empty one), or the ones you have created specifically? I suspect you may have something heavy happening in your initialization or `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This happens for all view controllers I created specifically. The thing is that I create those in the `viewDidLoad` of the page view controller. So should't each view controller be ready to go when I call `setViewControllers()`?

Comment: @Dima You were right I was doing some stupid heavy loading in every view controller. Thank you for your help!

Comment: no problem, the sort of mistake you generally only make once :)